# AS3 -> PHP Foreign Characters giving incorrect information

Tags: php, actionscript-3

I'm far from an expert in PHP and I'm struggling to resolve an issue that I'm having here.

What I'm doing is pulling core information from this URL:
http://us.battle.net/wow/en/arena/kelthuzad/3v3/W%C3%BCstenfuchs%20zu%20gro%C3%9F/

In AS3 this provides me with the following, from the team name:

http://us.battle.net/wow/en/arena/kelthuzad/3v3/W%C3%BCstenfuchs%20zu%20gro%C3%9F/

Now, this is fine. If I decodeURI it, it gives me:

http://us.battle.net/wow/en/arena/kelthuzad/3v3/Wüstenfuchs zu groß/

My issue comes when I'm sending the information from AS3 to PHP. I'm doing it with encoding intact, however no matter what I try PHP is reading the code incorrectly. This is the output:

var9=http://us.battle.net/wow/en/arena/kelthuzad/3v3/WÃ¼stenfuchs zu groÃ/

Even when I try to decode this, it gives the exact same output. If I send it from AS3 to PHP already decoded, it again gives the same result as above.

My code for AS3 is:

```
var phpVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();            

phpVars.team = _team;

urlRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
urlRequest.data = phpVars;

urlLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, returnResult);
urlLoader.load(urlRequest);
```

My code for PHP is:

```
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
    function updateData(){    
         $team2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['team']);
         echo("var9=".$team2);
         $sql = "INSERT INTO title_test SET field1='$team2'";
         mysql_query($sql);
     }
```

This puts into the database:

```
http://us.battle.net/wow/en/arena/kelthuzad/3v3/WÃ¼stenfuchs zu groÃŸ/
```

It's also worth noting that I'm trying to do a query with the $team2 data within PHP that is also failing, as it is not encoding correctly.

What step am I missing here?

Edit: utf-8 is enabled on the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after much heartache and many headaches, I have now got this to work... However the method that makes it work seems very strange and not best practise.

AS3 is now:

```
var phpVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();            

phpVars.team = decodeURI(_team);

urlRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
urlRequest.data = phpVars;

urlLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, returnResult);
urlLoader.load(urlRequest);
```

PHP is now:

```
$team2 = ($_POST['team']);
echo("var9=".$team2);
$sql = "INSERT INTO title_test SET field1='$team2'";
mysql_query($sql);
```

Connect.php is now

```
mysql_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name);

mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8'); 

mysql_select_db($db_name) or die (mysql_error());
```

This now correctly returns information into the database and allows the URL queries to work. The echo'd information back into Flash still shows incorrectly, though.

I'll leave this open, as I'm certain that this method is incorrect. I'm almost certain that you should leave it encoded going out of AS3 and unencode it in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Per http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html , add

```
mysql_query('SET NAMES UTF8');
```

just before

```
mysql_query($sql);
```

If that doesn't work, then make sure you are sending UTF8 to the server:

```
echo 'team2=', bin2hex($team2);
```

You should see

```
team2=57c3bc7374656e6675636873207a752067726fc39f
```

if you are sending UTF8.

Comment: Using the mysql_query line has now allowed the correct input into the database, but only if I do phpVars.team = decodeURI(_team) inside Flash. If I don't decode it in Flash, regardless that it's being decoded in PHP it enters the incorrect information into the DB. I did an echo of your line and the echo given back to Flash returned this: team2=687474703a2f2f75732e626174746c652e6e65742f776f772f656e2f6172656e612f6b656c7468757a61642f3376332f57c3bc7374656e6675636873207a752067726fc39f2f